# When $mB \neq B$? $m$ is a maximal ideal of $A$, $A \subseteq B$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, flatness

Let $A \subseteq B$ be commutative rings, $m$ a maximal ideal of $A$.
When $mB \neq B$?

This is true when $A \subseteq B$ is faithfully flat.
(If I am not wrong, this is also true when $A \subseteq B$ is integral).
Any other ideas are welcome.

Please notice: A similar (but not identical, I think) question is:  [When does $\mathfrak{a}B\cap A = \mathfrak{a}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194261/when-does-mathfrakab-cap-a-mathfraka/194306#194306), since the property I am talking about is slightly more general then $IB \cap A =I$, for every ideal $I$ of $A$.
Indeed, let $m$ be a maximal ideal of $A$. Then, in particular,  $mB \cap A=m$ and if $mB=B$ we would get $A= B \cap A = mB \cap A=m$, a contradiction to the maximality of $m$. So, "$IB \cap A =I$ implies $mB \neq B$".
(An exercise in Atiyah-MacDonald, which was mentioned in the second answer of [When does $\mathfrak{a}B\cap A = \mathfrak{a}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194261/when-does-mathfrakab-cap-a-mathfraka/194306#194306) shows that for a flat extension those two properties are equivalent).

**EDIT:** After not receiving any comments here, I have also posted this question in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/213160/when-mb-neq-b-m-is-a-maximal-ideal-of-a-a-subseteq-b?noredirect=1#comment528302_213160).